# How to know if i have clicked on a cell within the CellMouseDownEvent

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView which includes a table that does not fill it fully. It looks like this:

[image]

To get a Context Menu on Right Click I have several checks in the _CellMouseDown() event (the behaviour of which I need because with this event it selects the row before the click and several other things and so i can't get something like cellmouseclick or the like). But if i have any row selected and Right Click in the gray area below it still counts and I don't want that.

Is there a way to know if I have clicked an actual cell?

My friend suggested that I'd make a boolean with CellMouseEnter/Leave to know if I am in a cell but there has to be another way right?

Edit:
Here is the code. Sorry if it is a bit messy:

```
private void dataGridViewAlarmList_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if( e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            if( e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && e.ColumnIndex != -1 )
            {
                if( !dataGridViewAlarmList.SelectedRows.Contains( dataGridViewAlarmList.Rows[e.RowIndex] ) )
                {
                    dataGridViewAlarmList.ClearSelection();
                    dataGridViewAlarmList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
                    dataGridViewAlarmList.CurrentCell = dataGridViewAlarmList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];
                    dataGridViewAlarmList.Focus();
                }
            }

            if( dataGridViewAlarmList.SelectedRows.Count == 1 )
            {
                if( !bWorkRemote )
                {
                    ContextItemEditGrid.Enabled = true;
                }
                ContextItemViewMTSGrid.Enabled = true;
                ContextItemFindNode.Enabled = true;
                if( !bWorkRemote )
                {
                    ContextItemAcknowledgeGrid.Enabled = true;
                }
                if( dataGridViewAlarmList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "General Spectra" ||
                    dataGridViewAlarmList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "General Spectra Order" ||
                    dataGridViewAlarmList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "Vibration Spectra" ||
                    dataGridViewAlarmList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "Vibration Spectra Order" )
                {
                    ContextItemViewMTSGridTrendData.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ContextItemViewMTSGridTrendData.Enabled = false;
                }
                dataGridViewAlarmList.ContextMenuStrip = DataGridContextMenu;
            }
            else if( dataGridViewAlarmList.SelectedRows.Count > 1 )
            {
                ContextItemEditGrid.Enabled = false;
                ContextItemViewMTSGrid.Enabled = false;
                ContextItemFindNode.Enabled = false;
                if( !bWorkRemote )
                {
                    ContextItemAcknowledgeGrid.Enabled = true;
                }
                dataGridViewAlarmList.ContextMenuStrip = DataGridContextMenu;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridViewAlarmList.ClearSelection();
            dataGridViewAlarmList.ContextMenuStrip = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code. [The event's argument, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellmouseeventargs?view=netcore-3.1) already contains the coordinates of the cell. DataGridView handles conditional context menus through the [DataGridView.CellContextMenuStripNeeded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontextmenustripneeded?view=netcore-3.1) event

Comment: You may also want to switch to the CellContentClicked event.

Comment: @TaW I tested this out and it does not work with right click apparently. Also it does not seem to trigger every time. Sadly I dont have time to test it further.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I also tested it with the coordinates (if you mean e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex). My problem is that the grey area does trigger the event but does not set the coordinates anew. They are the last ones that where clicked before.

Comment: Because at `MouseDown` the selection *hasn't* changed yet. I suspect if you check the `CurrentCell` property you'll see the same. The gray area *can't* cause a cell change either. Have you tried the `MenuStripNeeded` event instead of MouseDown, checking `CurrentCell` to see which is the current active cell?

Comment: _Also it does not seem to trigger every time._ As the name inplies it only trigger when you hit the content, not an empty part of the cell. - You can use the MOuseDown event and do a HitTest to check if a Cell has been hit: `if (dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)...dostuff..`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos CurrentCell would probably yield the same result because the active cell did not Change. MenuStripNeeded looks promising. Sadly I ran out of time for this task and went with my workaround. Thank you for your help tho.

Comment: @T.Kogler that's not how software development works. You now have to support that workaround, probably wasting a lot more time than testing and using the correct event. Workarounds don't just accumulate technical debt that can be paid off, that's management speak for slacking. They create fatbergs that can't be brought down once they set without using explosive. Once you have enough workarounds, fixing anything or adding a new feature becomes a lot. harder. Do google `fatberg`

Comment: HitTest is the correct and recommended way. No need for a workaround, when you get the right result in one line of code..

Comment: @TaW HitTest seems like the correct answear for the Question and PanagiotisKanavos MenuStripNeeded is probably the best solution for my situation. If you want to post your answear I could accept it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't post answers here any longer. Feel free to self-answer the question..

Comment: @ Taw OK will do. May I ask why?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

HitTest is the correct answer if you want to check if you have actually hit a cell on your click.

If you are trying to do context menus in a table like me you should probably look for smarter ways like `DataGridView.CellContextMenuStripNeeded` which was also suggested in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

WPF already provides a ContextMenu, you don't have to do that yourself. You can add it to any item like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Information1" />
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Information2" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

There is much room for customisability of course.

Comment: for WinForms I found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHgJhZQs66k

Comment: I dont think thats the functionality I need. I have a functioning context menu. I also got a way to disable that. I even got a workaround with a boolean variable that tells me if I am in a cell or outside (via CellMouseEnter/Leave). But there has to be some better way to realise if I am in a cell or not when I use the CellMouseDown() event right?